# trying to escape quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, echo

I have tried numerous ways to print this line in a script:

```
alias myname='export PATH="/path/to/bin:$PATH"'
```

All of them have different problems.

The last I tried (and remember!) is:

```
printf '%s' '%s\n' 'alias myname=' ''\'"export PATH=\"/path/to/bin:$PATH\"" \'''  >> ~/.bashrc
```

but it doesn't work , it prints many times the PATH directory and in front of `alias myname` has `%sn`

(I prefer to use printf)

Comment: Why are you using two lots of `'%s'`? `printf` takes only one format string, so everything after that is interpreted as a literal (hence `%sn` appearing in the output).

Comment: @JigglyNaga:It doesn't work with one either.I used 2 because I have 2 stings. `alias myname` and the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you're trying to add the line

```
alias myname='export PATH="/path/to/bin:$PATH"'
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file

The obvious type of `echo` will fail because $PATH is expanded at the wrong time.

Instead we need to do some quote mixing:

```
echo "alias myname='export PATH=\"/path/to/bin:\$PATH\"'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now you say, for some reason, you want to use `printf`.  So we can do similar:

```
printf "%s\n" "alias myname='export PATH=\"/path/to/bin:\$PATH\"'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you want to treat the two sides of the `=` as separate strings:

```
printf "%s=%s\n" "alias myname" "'export PATH=\"/path/to/bin:\$PATH\"'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

And so on.

(`printf` only takes one format argument and then a list of values).

Comment: :Thanks!Finally!!I saw that `$` wants also `\`..

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy solutions. One is to use a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) instead of quote marks. Use the quoted form of the here document (where the `<<EOF` part contains a quote character) to turn off variable and command substitution inside the here document.

```
cat <<\EOF >>~/.bashrc
alias myname='export PATH="/path/to/bin:$PATH"'
EOF
```

The other is to use single quotes around the string you want to print. You can effectively escape a single quote in a single-quoted literal by using `'\''` — end the single-quoted literal, append a literal single quote, and start a new single-quoted literal.

```
echo 'alias myname='\''export PATH="/path/to/bin:$PATH"'\'''
```

(You can optimize away the final empty string literal `''`.)

On some shells, `echo` command doesn't print its argument literally, which is why the robust way to print a string is with `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'alias myname='\''export PATH="/path/to/bin:$PATH"'\'''
```

In this specific case, `echo` works too since the only expansions it performs concern backslashes and a leading `-`.